# Adding text to fractions raises error

Tags: math-mode, errors, amsmath, fractions

I'm new to LaTeX. I searched for a while and since I couldn't find any answers, decided to ask it here.

I'm trying to create a multi-line fraction that has text for my thesis. When I compile the command I have in a separate file it works fine and I get what I want, but when I add it to `thesis.tex` that has my university thesis package it raises "! Undefined control sequence".

Is there a way to fix this problem?

This is what I have:

```
\usepackage{etex}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{citesort}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage[center,normalsize]{subfigure}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}



\begin{document}
\begin{multline*}
G
=
\frac
{
\text{
\begin{tabular}{c}
number of subset of four nodes
\\
such that condition
\end{tabular}
}
}
{
\text{ 
\begin{tabular}{c}
number of all possible combinations of four nodes 
\\
that contribute to condition
\end{tabular}
}
}
\\
=
\frac
{
\text{
\begin{tabular}{c}
number of subset of four nodes 
\\
such that condition
\end{tabular}
}
}
{
\sum_{1\leq j\leq t \colon n_j>3} \binom{n_j}{4} 
}
<
1-\eta
\end{multline*}
\end{document}
```

which If I run in a separate file gives me this:

[image]

but when I run it in my `thesis.tex` I get this error

```
! Undefined control sequence.
\text #1->\hbox {\rm
\ #1\ \/}
l.1018 \end{multline*}
The control sequence at the end of the top line
of your error message was never \def'ed. If you have
misspelled it (e.g., `\hobx'), type `I' and the correct
spelling (e.g., `I\hbox'). Otherwise just continue,
and I'll forget about whatever was undefined.
```

Comment: Welcome! Don't use `\rm`. Use `\rmfamily` instead. The former is obsolete by a few decades.

Comment: If you need further help, please provide complete but minimal code which gives the error when compiled. The code you've given will produce an error, but not the one you've quoted. Note also that `subfigure` is obsolete and ought not be used. I guess you are using a KOMA class. They don't support the obsolete font switches any longer.

Comment: The `subfigure` package is obsolete and deprecated. Use either `subfig` or `subcaption` instead.

Comment: preferable to `\rmfamily` (since you're using `\text`) would be `\textrm`.  with `amsmath` this ensures that the argument remains upright even in italic (e.g. theorems) environments, as well as being set in the "correct" size for the context.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need any `\text` command: \begin{tabular} enters text mode. However I propose a shorter syntax with the `stackengine` package.

Also, note package `etex` isn't required any more since 2015, `subfigure` is obsolete and no more maintained. Use the `subfigure` environment from `subcaption` instead. Finally, needless to load both `graphicx` and `graphics`, as the former loads the latter.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage{frcursive}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{arrayjobx}
\usepackage[table]{xcolor}
\usepackage{multirow}
    \usepackage{citesort}%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[usestackEOL]{stackengine}

\begin{document}

\begin{multline*}
G =
\frac{\Centerstack{number of subset of four nodes\\such that condition}}
{\Centerstack{number of all possible combinations of four nodes \\
that contribute to condition}}%
\\
=
\frac{\Centerstack{number of subset of four nodes \\ such that condition}}
{\sum_{1\leq j\leq t \colon n_j>3} \binom{n_j}{4}}%
< 1-\eta
\end{multline*}

\end{document}
```

[image]